# Given the subgroups $H$ and $N$ normal of group $G$, what is ${\rm Im}(\phi)$ regarding $\phi:H\to G/N$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Given the subgroups $H$ and $N$ normal of group $G$ and let $\phi: H \rightarrow G/N$ defined as $\phi(h)=hN$ (standard canonical group homomorphism by $\phi: G \rightarrow G/N$), then the ${\rm Im}(\phi)$ should be ${\rm Im}(\phi) = HN/N$ by my old lecture notes, but I am looking at this for 10 minutes now and I can't see (anymore) why this should be true

Comment: Maybe you should remember that, if $N$ is normal, then $KN$ is precisely the set of elements of the form $kn$, because $knhm= kh(h^{-1}nh)m)$ and $nk = k(k^{-1}nk)$

Comment: Yeah I know what these elements look like and I also know that (by using properties of a normal group) the multiplication/inverse of 2 elements also do look like this, but I don't know how this helps me here or I am just missing the point of your last argument

Comment: Wait, can't I just simply look at the cosets of $HN/N$ and conclude (due to cosets being disjoint) that $hN$ and $hnN$ (for any n $\in$ N) are the same coset since $n^{-1}, e \in N$, therefore $HN/N$ is the disjoint union of $hN$ with $h \in H$ (ignore the fact that some hN might be the same for now)? Wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is why I said my earlier comment.

Comment: Alright, alright! Thank you very much!

Comment: The image is isomorphic to $H/H\cap N$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem. By the Second, $H/H\cap N\cong HN/N$. If you look at the isomorphism described in the standard proof, you will see that it is exactly what you want.

Comment: I discovered only today by speaking with a friend about the aforementioned problem that my prof defined a different theorem to be the second isomorphism theorem: Let $H,N$ be normal subgroups of $G$ with properties: $N \subseteq H$. Then it follows: $H/N$ is normal regarding $G/N$ and the canonical homomorphism $(G/N)/(G/H) \rightarrow G/H$ is an isomorphism.